# How to connect with HFSQL database server via asp .net Core 6 web API C# project to access data?

Tags: c#, odbc, asp.net-core-webapi, oledb, windev

This HFSQL database server is connected to a WINDEV desktop application in another location and I am trying to convert it to web application using .Net Core 6 Web API and some frontend framework. With HFSQL Control center I can connect to database without any issue to manage database. But, I need to connect it with my web api project.

I tried connection using OdbcConnection string by installing ODBC drivers provided by [pcsoft](https://windev.com/ts/download/common-modules-28/wx28_95g.htm)

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Driver={HFSQL};Server Name=;Server Port=4900;Database=;UId=;PWD=;"
}
```

but failed attempt with an error

```
ERROR [08001] The SQL code defining the <Date_Added> calculated item is incorrect.
Error in the SQL code of the expression. 

Unable to load C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\PC SOFT\28.0\ODBC\Win64x86\wd280cpl64.dll DLL
Error detected:
 >>>>WL.DateDuJour()<<<<

System error code: 126
System error message:
The specified module could not be found.


Debugging information:
DLL qui provoque le chargement : WDVM
DLL a charger : wd280cpl64.dll
DLL chargee : C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\PC SOFT\28.0\ODBC\Win64x86\wd280cpl64.dll
Chemin des DLL : C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\PC SOFT\28.0\ODBC\Win64x86\
Chemin de l'EXE :
```

I tried inserting dll file manually and then api application got crashed while trying to connect without any error message.

```
"OLEDBConnect": "Provider=PCSOFT.HFSQL;Data Source=***.***.com:4900;User ID=*****;Password=******;Initial Catalog=*****;"
```

With OLEDB driver using above connection string application get crashed OLEDB drivers provided by [pcsoft](https://windev.com/ts/download/common-modules-28/wx28_95g.htm).

With some other database instance it works fine, but when connecting to my target database this error occur.

Comment: I removed connectionstring sensitive data for security purpose but you can get an idea

Comment: The dll need to be in the same folder as the c# executable.  Is that happening?  This sound like a deployment issue.  Manually put the dll in the same folder as the executable and see if code runs.  Later you can fix the deployment issue.

Comment: This is not related to the <SQL> _language. Add a tag for the dbms instead.

Comment: I tried downloading and inserting dll file too from [here] (https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/wd280cpl64#google_vignette) but the result was same. @jdweng

Comment: Looks like PC Soft needs to be loaded on the machine where code is being run.  The code modifies the System Date of the machine.  So you probably need Admin rights.  See https://doc.windev.com/en-US/?3027016